# How can I recall a variable that was created inside a for loop?

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm trying to figure out how I can call a variable that was created inside a for loop.

There is a variable created with the name of each of the zones in DNS IE `${test.com} ${test2.com}` that contains all of the dns records for that zone. I would like to call the variable and append the zone to the end of each record as when they are called with `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` it doesn't show the complete FQDN. I'm not sure how to dynamically recall the variable that was created so I can continue on with the rest of the script.
Edit - I'm trying to access these variables from outside the for loop.

```
ForEach ($Zone in $Zones) {
    remove-variable -name $zone.zonename # <-- this is only here for testing while running the scripts or it errors when creating the new variables
#create a new variable with the name of each zone
    $dnsrecords = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zone.ZoneName -ComputerName $DNSServer
    New-Variable -name $zone.zonename -value $dnsrecords
        ForEach ($testhost in $zone.zonename) {
            $fqdn += $testhost.Hostname + $zone.zonename 
        }
#Create a new variable with a name of each zone variable
    $zonenamevariables += $zone.zonename
}
```

This is the entire script thus far.

```
$DNSServer = "dns.somedomain.com"
$Zones = @(Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $DNSServer)
$zonenamevariables = @()
$fqdn = @()

#Grab all records for each zone discovered
ForEach ($Zone in $Zones) {
    Write-Host "$($Zone.ZoneName)"
    remove-variable -name $zone.zonename # <-- this is only here for testing while running the scripts or it errors when creating the new variables
#create a new variable with the name of each zone
    $dnsrecords = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zone.ZoneName -ComputerName $DNSServer
    New-Variable -name $zone.zonename -value $dnsrecords
        foreach ($testhost in $zone.zonename) {
            $fqdn += $testhost.Hostname + $zone.zonename 
        }
#Create a new variable with a name of each zone variable
    $zonenamevariables += $zone.zonename
}
#Setup variable for only A records
$arecords = $test | Where-Object RecordType -eq A

#Setup variable with only records name and IP
$cleanrecords = $arecords | Select-Object HostName, @{Name='RecordData';Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address.IPAddressToString}}

$cleanrecords | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\test.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just retrieve it with `Get-Variable`

```
$current = Get-Variable $zone.zonename
```

It will have properties including name and value. To get the contents of the variable is as simple as

```
$current.value
```

If you want to collect a list of the variables you create, use the `-PassThru` parameter. Perhaps an example will help.

```
$variables = 1..3 | % {
    New-Variable -Name $_ -Value $_ -PassThru
}
```

Now we have three new variables, named 1, 2, and 3. We can get all their values individually in a loop

```
$variables | foreach {
    $current = Get-Variable $_.name
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        VariableName  = $current.Name
        VariableValue = $current.value
    }
}

VariableName VariableValue
------------ -------------
1                        1
2                        2
3                        3
```

Or all at once

```
(Get-Variable $variables.name).value

1
2
3
```

You can also remove them all at once if you like

```
Remove-Variable $variables.name
```

Another example using a hashtable with key/value pair we use for the name/value of the new variable. Note again the -passthru option which shows the newly create variables in the output.

```
@{
    ZoneA = "8.8.8.8"
    ZoneB = "9.9.9.9"
}.GetEnumerator()|%{New-Variable -Name $_.name -Value $_.value -PassThru}

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                          
ZoneA                          8.8.8.8                                                                                                                                        
ZoneB                          9.9.9.9
```

Simply put the collection variable at the beginning of a loop, function, etc that is creating the output to have powershell quickly collect them all. This is a much faster approach then `$something = @(); $something += $something else` and it's easier to type as well!

```
$collectionvariable = @{
    ZoneA = "8.8.8.8"
    ZoneB = "9.9.9.9"
}.GetEnumerator()|%{New-Variable -Name $_.name -Value $_.value -PassThru}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm attempting to call the variables from outside the for loop, which was why I stored their names in `$zonenamevariables`. The `$zone` variable is only holding info for the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: Nothing changes. What do you mean by call them, get the contents? If you have more that one then do the same as the example but in a loop. If you need more help just say what you’re *actually* trying to do with them

Comment: My end goal here is to get a workable list of FQDN's within the domain with IP's. So I was trying to come up with a way to add the domain name to the end of each domain that was pulled using `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` because the output of the command is "Hostname - test" instead of "Hostname - test.company.com" This is why I was trying to assign the entries to a variable with the domain name as the name of the variable.

Comment: Hopefully my examples help clarify. I think in your case you just simply need to run your same loop again just using Get-Variable instead - OR - use the -passthru to collect them, either way.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense to me. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable a script-scope variable with $script:ZoneNameVariable and initialize the variable outside of the loop.

E.g.:

```
$script:zonenamevariable = @()
foreach($zone in $zones){
    $script:zonenamevariable += $zone.name
}
echo $script:zonenamevariable
```

Comment: The scope modifier doesn't help OP in this case, it's in the same scope already.

Comment: It's not. The variable declared within the loop is in local scope. By declaring it as script scope that variable is now available everywhere within the script. An item is visible in the scope in which it was created and in any child scopes (the corollary to that is that it is NOT visible to parent scopes). So it is visible in the loop, and any sub-loops within the loop; it is not visible outside the loop. By declaring it outside the loop it should be visible within the loop. But to avoid the loop creating a local variable of the same name you use the script scope identifier.

Comment: That is incorrect. Please see my examples above. A foreach loop scope is still accessible to the calling scope. Now if it was a function or a remote call, then perhaps.